# Is there anyway to return other data inside of the javascript treemap json?

Tags: javascript, json, callback, treemap

I have an asp.net mvc website [and am using javascript treemap control](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example1.code.html) to display a heatmap.  This control works great but i wanted to see if i can stick some other json fields into the callback that is used to update another div.

Does anyone know if this is possible.  Right now I have to bounce back and forth and do 2 seperate ajax calls but i wanted to see if i can pass along this info along with the treemap json response.

Comment: Where in the code are you making the callbacks? Off hand I see a couple of event handlers, but I do not see any ajax calls in what you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you would need to do is a single call in which you work out the callback yourself. Here the json would be a structure like

```
var data = {
  heatmap_data: {}
  other_data: {}
}
```

and next call

```
tm.loadJSON(data.heatmap_data);
```

to load the heatmap data and use all the other data to your own liking. That should do the trick right? At least, that is if loadJSON takes an object as seems to be the case. Still, this answer seems too simple, so I might be totally missing the point.

Answer (score 0):

You have a defined structure for your TreeMap, basically you have every node with keys `id`, `name`, `data` and `children`. As far as I read in the docs, there is no restriction on other keys. So you can add extra keys inside the `data` attribute.

For example your json response could be like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "myCustomData": { /* your data here */ }
    },
    "id": "root",
    "name": "Top Albums",
    "children": [
        {
            "data": {
                "playcount": 547,
                "$area": 547, 
                "myCustomData": { /* your data here */ }
            },
            "id": "artist_A Perfect Circle",
            "name": "A Perfect Circle"

        }
    ]
}
```

When you want to use your extra data you do this:

```
... 
onClick: function(node) {
      ...
      if( node.data.myCustomData ){
           /*** you have data, do something here ***/
      }
}
```

Here you have a **[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/guumaster/buTtE/)** with an alert when you click on nodes with `myCustomData`. mouse over the "Make yourself" box on top left corner to see custom data in the tooltip and an alert with the custom data on click.

Search the code for "mycustomdata" to see how it's done.